# Calculate whole points on a circle

Tags: c++, geometry

I've written a small program but the answer it gives is always wrong, here is the code

```
double radiusc;
double xcenter;
double ycenter;

bool onthecircle(int x,int y);


int main(void)
{
    int inputwait;

    printf("Please enter x coordinate of your center point: ");
    scanf("%d",&xcenter);

    printf("Please enter y coordinate of your center point: ");
    scanf("%d",&ycenter);

    printf("Please enter the radius of the circle: ");
    scanf("%d",&radiusc);

    double left_x = xcenter - radiusc;
    double left_y = ycenter;

    double down_x = xcenter;
    double down_y = ycenter - radiusc;

    if(left_x >= floor(left_x))
    {
        left_x = floor(left_x);
        int (left_x);
    }
    else
    {
        left_x = floor(left_x) + 1;
        int (left_x);
    }

    for(left_x; left_x<=xcenter; left_x++)
    {
        for(left_y;left_y>ycenter-radiusc;left_y--)
        {
            if(onthecircle(left_x,left_y))
                printf("Jest na kole: %d , %d \n", left_x,left_y);
        }
    }

    scanf("%i",&inputwait);

    return 0;
}

bool onthecircle(int x,int y)
{
    double t1= x - xcenter;
    double t2 = x - ycenter;

    if ((t1*t1 + t2*t2) > (0,9 *radiusc*radiusc) &&
        (t1*t1 + t2*t2) < (1,1 *radiusc*radiusc))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

}
```

When I debug, typing 0,0 as my center and r = 1, it gives me the point 0, and some big number, instead of saving 1 as the value for r, it gets a random huge number, and I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Comment: @myrkos: You can define it yourself (e.g., `typedef enum { false, true } bool;`, or in C99 you can `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: It would have to be C99 as all variables are not declared at the top of the function.  My question is; what is `int(left_x)` doing?

Comment: @EdS.: I think it's parsed as a variable declaration; the parentheses are superfluous.  (I have no idea what it's *supposed* to be.)

Comment: changes the double which was floored to an int

Comment: i had the wrong parenthesis should be (int) x not int (x)

Comment: `(int)left_x` is an expression that yields the value of `left_x` (a `double`) converted to `int`.  You don't do anything with the result.  It's a legal statement, but it does nothing.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the problem Ed found, `0,9` is not a valid floating-point constant; you want `0.9`.  (Locale settings can affect input and output representations; they don't affect language syntax.)

The comma in `(0,9 *radiusc*radiusc)` is a comma operator, not a decimal point; you're multiplying the square of the radius by 9.

And you're missing the `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <math.h>` (for `floor()` at the top of your program (your compiler might let you get away with that, but it's *not* optional).

And the format in your `printf` calls is incorrect; you need `"%f"` or `"%g"` for `double'.

More:

Your use of a `double` as a loop control variable is questionable.  The call `scanf("%i",&inputwait);` to wait for input before terminating the program *without a prompt* is user-hostile.  There is no need to use global variables.  I don't know what `int (left_x);` is *supposed* to do; I think it's parsed as a declaration (of a variable that you never use), and the parentheses are superfluous.  Your use of the type name `bool` means either that you're compiling your code as C++, or that you have either a `#include <stdbool.h>` or a definition of `bool` that you haven't bothered to show us.

That's about as much debugging as I'm willing to do for now.  Fix these errors and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Your format to `scanf` is wrong; `%d` is for decimal integers.  You want `%lf` for `double`.

That said, why aren't you using C++ style I/O, i.e., `<iostream>`, `cout`, `cin`, etc.?  This looks like some ugly mix of C and C++.

Comment: @Keith: Thanks, missed the `l`.

Comment: so a long float is the same as a double?